# How to use addImageQuery from leafem package with leafletProxy() in R shiny app

Tags: leaflet-r

I'm writing a shiny app that generates a raster based on user input, and I would like to add this raster to a `leaflet` map and then have the raster values be displayed using `addImageQuery` from the `leafem` package.

So far I've only been able to use the `addImageQuery` function when I initially generate the map (see code block 1). However, when I first generate the map and then use `leafletProxy` to add the raster and image query, the raster is added to the map but the query does not work (see code block 2).

Code block 1 (`addImageQuery` works):

```
library(leaflet)
library(plainview)
library(leafem)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    leafletOutput("map")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap") %>%
      addRasterImage(poppendorf[[1]], project = TRUE, group = "poppendorf",
                     layerId = "poppendorf") %>%
      addImageQuery(poppendorf[[1]], project = TRUE,
                            layerId = "poppendorf",position="bottomleft",prefix = "") %>%
      addLayersControl(overlayGroups = "poppendorf")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Code block 2 (raster added on click, `addImageQuery` does not work):

```
library(leaflet)
library(plainview)
library(leafem)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    leafletOutput("map")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap") %>%
      setView(11.2,49.73,12)
  })

  counter <- reactiveValues(
    counter = 0
  )

  observeEvent(input$map_click,{
    counter$counter <- counter$counter + 1
    if (counter$counter == 1) {
      leafletProxy("map") %>%
        addRasterImage(poppendorf[[1]], project = TRUE, group = "poppendorf",
                       layerId = "poppendorf") %>%
        addImageQuery(poppendorf[[1]], project = TRUE,
                      layerId = "poppendorf",position="bottomleft",prefix = "") %>%
        addLayersControl(overlayGroups = "poppendorf")

    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Does anyone know a way to get the `addImageQuery` function to work with a `leafletProxy` call?

Comment: The addImageQuery seems to be working correctly in code block 2. I'm wondering if the authors fixed this issue in more recent versions of the leafem package.